# Add wrapper to Views Rest JSON Output

Tags: views, 8

I am rebuilding an API in Drupal. The structure of the JSON must remain the same.

I am using Views and Draggable Views so the user can order items on an overview page. I Enabled the view for exporting REST JSON.

The response JSON must have a structure like this

```
{
  items: [{...},{...}]
}
```

But currently views output is like this

```
{[{...},{...}]}
```

I already managed to get my desired output without views and a special export controller but unfortunately, I need draggable views in additions to views.
I also managed to create nested structures with Entity Normalizers inside an item but I want the whole output of the view is wrapped in "items".
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can create a new views style plugin based on the json one and just wrap the output with the additional layer.

Comment: Can't this even be done from a template?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a views style plugin to get through this fast. Here is an example of that, which adds an outer wrapper of `results` plus a `totalCount` item:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\views\style;

use Drupal\rest\Plugin\views\style\Serializer;

/**
 * The style plugin for serialized output formats.
 *
 * @ingroup views_style_plugins
 *
 * @ViewsStyle(
 *   id = "serializer_count",
 *   title = @Translation("Serializer with Count"),
 *   help = @Translation("Serializes views row data using the Serializer component and adds a count."),
 *   display_types = {"data"}
 * )
 */
class SerializerCount extends Serializer {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render() {
    $rows = [];

    if (isset($this->view->pager)) {
      $count = $this->view->pager->getTotalItems();
    }
    else {
      $count = 0;
    }

    // If the Data Entity row plugin is used, this will be an array of entities
    // which will pass through Serializer to one of the registered Normalizers,
    // which will transform it to arrays/scalars. If the Data field row plugin
    // is used, $rows will not contain objects and will pass directly to the
    // Encoder.
    foreach ($this->view->result as $row_index => $row) {
      $this->view->row_index = $row_index;
      $rows[$row_index] = $this->view->rowPlugin->render($row);
    }

    unset($this->view->row_index);

    // Get the content type configured in the display or fallback to the
    // default.
    if ((empty($this->view->live_preview))) {
      $content_type = $this->displayHandler->getContentType();
    }
    else {
      $content_type = !empty($this->options['formats']) ? reset($this->options['formats']) : 'json';
    }

    return $this->serializer->serialize(['results' => ['items' => $rows, 'totalCount' => (int) $count]], $content_type, ['views_style_plugin' => $this]);
  }

}
```

Then clear cache, and change the plugin for the View under "Style".

So in your case, the final line would look like:

```
return $this->serializer->serialize(['items' => $rows], $content_type, ['views_style_plugin' => $this]);
```

Comment: Thx for the help. Unfortunaly my plugin is not showing up in views under style? I put it in this directory: my_module/src/Plugin/views/style/MySerializer.php but not success. Do i have add some yml definitions etc.?

Comment: It works now with your code base. And i added my code. I think for the views plugin to work it is really important to have the comment section: ```/**
 * The style plugin for serialized output formats.
 *
 * @ingroup views_style_plugins
 *
 * @ViewsStyle(
 *   id = "serializer_count",
 *   title = @Translation("Serializer with Count"),
 *   help = @Translation("Serializes views row data using the Serializer component and adds a count."),
 *   display_types = {"data"}
 * )
 */ ```

Comment: Yes, you need the annotation so it is discovered.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal's Core Serializer does not provide options to customize the json, nor does it include the pagination data.

The [Pager Serializer](https://www.drupal.org/project/pager_serializer) module does include the pagination information, and the property names are customizable, so your api can remain unchanged.

By default, it produces something like this.

```
{
  rows: [
    {...},
    {...}
  ],
  pager: {
    current_page: 0,
    total_items: 6,
    total_pages: 2,
    items_per_page: 5,
  }
}
```

Use the module's configuration form to customize the *rows* key, and disable the unneeded properties to meet your needs.

```
{
  items: [
    {...},
    {...}
  ]
}
```

*or* if you need the total count as provided in the answer by @kevin.

```
{
  items: [
    {...},
    {...}
  ],
  totalCount: 6
}
```

*or*

```
{
  items: [
    {...},
    {...}
  ],
  pager: {
    total_items: 6
  }
}
```